# Reading the PostgreSQL hstore type with F#

Tags: postgresql, f#, type-providers

I'm trying to read PostgreSQL database with F#. The table I read contains column of `hstore` type but I'm not able to access this column.

I tried two approaches. First with using `SqlDataProvider`

```
type sql = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString = connString,
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.POSTGRESQL, 
              ResolutionPath = resPath,
              IndividualsAmount = 1000,
              UseOptionTypes = true, Owner="public">

let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

for item in ctx.Public.Articles.Take(10) do printfn "%s" item.???
```

My item doesn't contain columns at all.

When I use another approach

```
type dbSchema = 
    SqlEntityConnection<
        ConnectionString=connString, 
        Provider="Npgsql">

let ctx = dbSchema.GetDataContext()    

for item in ctx.articles do printfn "%s" item.???
```

The item contains all columns except column of `hstore` type.

In the code of [SqlProvider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/blob/master/src/SQLProvider/Providers.Postgresql.fs) there I see some mapping of `hstore` in the PostgreSQL provider but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: What do you see in intellisense when using the SqlDataProvider - do you see any other column?